# Menu Bar, Color, and Image not adding to frame

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a menubar calling other classes through object creation, as well as trying to add an image to the frame.

The code does seem to compile, but none of the components I placed in the code seem to be appearing?

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import javax.swing.border.*;

  public class Operation 
     extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
  {
      String op="",pre="";

      JFrame calFrame = new JFrame("Calculator");

      JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();

     JMenu homeMenu = new JMenu("Home");
        JMenuItem welcomeScreen = new JMenuItem("Welcome Screen");
        JMenuItem listHome = new JMenuItem("List Accessories");
     JMenu jumpMenu = new JMenu("Jump To");
         JMenuItem jtSclingTool = new JMenuItem("Scaling Tool");
         JMenuItem jtMetricConv = new JMenuItem("Metric Converter");
     JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem helpScreen = new JMenuItem("Help Screen");
     JMenu exitMenu = new JMenu("Exit");
        JMenuItem exitToHome = new JMenuItem("Exit to Welcome Screen");
        JMenuItem exitProgram= new JMenuItem("Exit Program");

 public void Calculator()
 {
     calFrame.setBounds(0,0,1920,1080);

     calFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     calFrame.setLayout(null);

     JTextField txtid = new JTextField();
     txtid.setBounds(20,20,400,100);
     calFrame.add(txtid);
     txtid.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 19));
     txtid.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
     txtid.setText("0");
     txtid.setEnabled(false);

     mainBar.add(homeMenu);
     mainBar.add(jumpMenu);
     mainBar.add(helpMenu);
     mainBar.add(exitMenu);

     homeMenu.add(welcomeScreen);
     homeMenu.add(listHome);
     jumpMenu.add(jtSclingTool);
     jumpMenu.add(jtMetricConv);
     helpMenu.add(helpScreen);
     exitMenu.add(exitToHome);
     exitMenu.add(exitProgram);

     welcomeScreen.addActionListener(this);
     listHome.addActionListener(this);
     helpScreen.addActionListener(this);
     exitToHome.addActionListener(this);
     exitProgram.addActionListener(this);
     jtSclingTool.addActionListener(this);
     jtMetricConv.addActionListener(this);

     JButton a = new JButton ("1");
     a.setBounds(20,440,100,100);
     calFrame.add(a);

     JButton b = new JButton ("2");
     b.setBounds(120,440,100,100);
     calFrame.add(b);

     JButton c = new JButton ("3");
     c.setBounds(220,440,100,100);
     calFrame.add(c);

     JButton d = new JButton ("4");
     d.setBounds(20,340,100,100);
     calFrame.add(d);

     JButton e = new JButton ("5");
     e.setBounds(120,340,100,100);
     calFrame.add(e);

     JButton f = new JButton ("6");
     f.setBounds(220,340,100,100);
     calFrame.add(f);

     JButton g = new JButton ("7");
     g.setBounds(20,240,100,100);
     calFrame.add(g);

     JButton h = new JButton ("8");
     h.setBounds(120,240,100,100);
     calFrame.add(h);

     JButton i = new JButton ("9");
     i.setBounds(220,240,100,100);
     calFrame.add(i);

     JButton j = new JButton ("0");
     j.setBounds(120,540,100,100);
     calFrame.add(j);

     JButton k = new JButton ("+");
     k.setBounds(320,240,100,200);
     calFrame.add(k);

     JButton l = new JButton ("-");
     l.setBounds(320,140,100,100);
     calFrame.add(l);
     //
     JButton m = new JButton ("*");
     m.setBounds(220,140,100,100);
     calFrame.add(m);

     JButton n = new JButton ("/");
     n.setBounds(120,140,100,100);
     calFrame.add(n);

     JButton o = new JButton ("=");
     o.setBounds(320,440,100,200);
     calFrame.add(o);

     JButton p = new JButton (".");
     p.setBounds(220,540,100,100);
     calFrame.add(p);

     JButton q = new JButton ("Del");
     q.setBounds(20,540,100,100);
     calFrame.add(q);

     JButton r = new JButton ("AC");
     r.setBounds(20,140,100,100);
     calFrame.add(r);

     calFrame.setVisible(true);
 }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
     a.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("1");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("1");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"1");
        }
     });

     b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("2");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("2");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"2");
        }
     });

     c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("3");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("3");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"3");
        }
     });

     d.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("4");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("4");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"4");
        }
     });

     e.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("5");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("5");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"5");
        }
     });

     f.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
        if(op.equals("="))
        {
             txtid.setText("6");
             op="";
         }
        else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("6");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"6");
        }
     });

     g.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("7");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("7");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"7");
        }
     });

     h.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("8");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("8");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"8");
        }
     });

     i.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("9");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("9");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"9");
        }
     });


     j.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("0");
             op="";
         }
         else if(txtid.getText().equals("0"))
            txtid.setText("0");
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+"0");
        }
     });

     k.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="+";
         pre=txtid.getText();
         txtid.setText("");
        }
     });

     l.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="-";
         pre=txtid.getText();
         txtid.setText("");
        }
     });

     m.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="*";
         pre=txtid.getText();
         txtid.setText("");
        }
     });

     n.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="/";
         pre=txtid.getText();
         txtid.setText("");
        }
     });

      p.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         if(op.equals("="))
         {
             txtid.setText("0.");
             op="";
         }
         else
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText()+".");
     }
     });

     q.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="del";
         String str=txtid.getText();
         int p = str.length();
         if(p-1!=0)
             txtid.setText(txtid.getText().substring(0,p-1));
         else
             txtid.setText("0");
        }
     });

     r.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {
         op="";  //AC
         pre=""; //AC
         txtid.setText("0");

        }
     });

     o.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
     {       
         switch(op)
         {
             case "":
                 txtid.setText("0");
                 break;
             case "+":
                 txtid.setText((Float.parseFloat(pre)+Float.parseFloat(txtid.getText()))+"");
                 break;
             case "-":
                 txtid.setText((Float.parseFloat(pre)-Float.parseFloat(txtid.getText()))+"");
                 break;
             case "*":
                 txtid.setText((Float.parseFloat(pre)*Float.parseFloat(txtid.getText()))+"");
                 break;
             case "/":
                 txtid.setText((Float.parseFloat(pre)/Float.parseFloat(txtid.getText()))+"");
                 break;
             case "=":
                 break;
             }
             op="=";
         }
     });

        String buttonCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        AlgebraAccessories mainWindow = new AlgebraAccessories();
        ListAccessories listAccessories = new ListAccessories();
        Scaling sclTool = new Scaling();
        MetricConverter mtrConv = new MetricConverter();

        if (buttonCommand.equals("Welcome Screen"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            mainWindow.MainWelcomeWindow();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("List Accessories"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            listAccessories.selectionWindow();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("Scaling Tool"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            sclTool.Scale();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("Metric Converter"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            mtrConv.MetricConverter();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("Help"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            mainWindow.MainWelcomeWindow();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("Exit to Welcome Screen"))
        {
            calFrame.dispose();
            mainWindow.MainWelcomeWindow();
        }
        else if (buttonCommand.equals("Exit Program"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Operation mainGui = new Operation();
    mainGui.Calculator();
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you write hundreds of lines of code with components and ActionListeners without doing some basic testing along the way to see if the code is working? Why does your class extend JFrame and then create a JFrame. You now have two frames. So start over with a simple example that creates a frame and add a menubar to the frame. Then when that works add a component or 2 to the frame. You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for a simple working example to get your started. Change the example.

Comment: Also, don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The tutorial also has a section on using layout managers. So read the different sections from the Swing tutorial to learn Swing basics. Also section have working examples you can download and play with.

Comment: I did actually test the code along the way, and up until all of the buttons and action listeners were created, the code worked fine ( the calculator works perfect i am able to enter numbers and have it work). But when i add the other components it does not work that is my question on why it wont.

Comment: Again, there is too much code for us to look at. So you need to simplify the code. If you were able to add components before then there should be no difference now. As I have stated, the whole design of your class using an null layout and setBounds() will cause issues as the code gets more complex because you, instead of the layout manager needs to manage the size/location of all the components. So I suggested you code properly and use layout managers.

Comment: *"But when i add the **other** components.."* you are providing conflicting information, given in the question it states *"but **none** of the components I placed in the code seem to be appearing"* which is it? They can't both be correct. In fact, let's make it more specific still - what is the **first** component added that fails to appear? Take out all the components beyond that - they are irrelevant to the immediate problem. *"the calculator works perfect"* That seems irrelevant to the problem as well. Prove it by removing all the action listeners. Is the problem still there? ..

Comment: .. It sounds like it will be, so none of the listeners should be in the [mcve] posted for others to look at. Posting a long code makes it harder for you to identify the problem & harder for us to even care. After all, if you could not be bothered trimming the code down to the minimum required to display the problem, why should anyone else? Creating an MCVE requires effort on your part, but by not doing it, it implies you see your time is being more important than ours. We know otherwise. It is your problem after all, and you are the only person here who actually has anything to lose if it ..

Comment: .. has bugs. So your call as to whether going to that effort is worth your time, but if not, you should also consider not posting here on SO.